# How do I cancel a 'window.open' from a commandbutton?

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton, action, oncomplete

I have the following CommandButton:

```
<apex:commandButton value="View Statement"
                  action="{!openInvestmentStatement}" title="View Statement"
                  oncomplete="window.open('{!redirectURL}','_blank','height=800,width=600,location=no,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=1', 1)"/>
```

This opens a Visualforce PDF page and works fine. Problem is if there is no data (ie the PDF will be blank), how do I cancel the window.open?

Answer (score 0):

Set a `boolean` value from your controller from which you can identify if the PDF page will remain blank or it will contain values.

And using that `boolean` value, call a `javascript` function from `oncomplete` event of `commandButton`, if the `boolean` is `true`, do not redirect to PDF page.

Changes in Apex Controller

```
public boolean isPDFBlank {get;set;}

public PageReference openInvestmentStatement(){
    //all other existing logic
    if(PDFPage is blank) //depending on your logic
        isPDFBlank = true;
    else 
        isPDFBlank = false;
}
```

Changes in visualforce page

```
function openPDFPage(){
    if({!isPDFBlank} == true){
        alert('PDF page is blank')
    } else {
        window.open('{!redirectURL}','_blank','height=800,width=600,location=no,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=1', 1);
    }
}

<apex:commandButton value="View Statement"
                  action="{!openInvestmentStatement}" title="View Statement"
                  oncomplete="openPDFPage()"/>
```